# Python - Web Scraping for Target

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get Chips names from this Target market [link](https://www.target.com/c/chips-snacks-grocery/-/N-5xsy7) and trying to get all 28 chips automatically in first page. I wrote this code. Opens the link, scrolls down (to fetch the names and pictures) and tries to get the names;

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager as CM

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

mobile_emulation = {
    "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.3; HTC One X Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19'
}
options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

bot = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CM().install(), options=options)

bot.get('https://www.target.com/c/chips-snacks-grocery/-/N-5xsy7')
bot.set_window_size(500, 950)
time.sleep(5)

for i in range(0,3):
    ActionChains(bot).send_keys(Keys.END).perform()
    time.sleep(1)

product_names = bot.find_elements_by_class_name('Link-sc-1khjl8b-0 styles__StyledTitleLink-mkgs8k-5 kdCHb inccCG h-display-block h-text-bold h-text-bs flex-grow-one')

hrefList = []
for e in product_names:
    hrefList.append(e.get_attribute('href'))

for href in hrefList:
    print(href)
```

When I inspect the names from browser, the common part of all chips is having `Link-sc-1khjl8b-0 styles__StyledTitleLink-mkgs8k-5 kdCHb inccCG h-display-block h-text-bold h-text-bs flex-grow-one` class name. So as you see I added `find_elements_by_class_name('Link-sc-1khjl8b-0 styles__StyledTitleLink-mkgs8k-5 kdCHb inccCG h-display-block h-text-bold h-text-bs flex-grow-one')` line. But it gives null result. What is wrong? Can you help me? Solution can be `selenium` or `bs4` doesnt matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works:

```
product_names = bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@data-test='list-entry-product-card']")

hrefList = []
for e in product_names:
    print(e.find_element_by_css_selector("a").get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: thank you for answer but I want to ask you to how we can get chips names ? this shows item urls

Comment: WIth `e.find_element_by_css_selector("a.kdCHb").get_attribute('text')`

Answer (score 3):

You can get all that data from the api as long as you feed in the correct key.

```
import requests


url = 'https://redsky.target.com/redsky_aggregations/v1/web/plp_search_v1'
payload = {
'key': 'ff457966e64d5e877fdbad070f276d18ecec4a01',
'category': '5xsy7',
'channel': 'WEB',
'count': '28',
'default_purchasability_filter': 'true',
'include_sponsored': 'true',
'offset': '0',
'page': '/c/5xsy7',
'platform': 'desktop',
'pricing_store_id': '1771',
'scheduled_delivery_store_id': '1771',
'store_ids': '1771,1768,1113,3374,1792',
'useragent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
'visitor_id': '0179C80AE1090201B5D5C1D895ADEA6C'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()    


for each in jsonData['data']['search']['products']:
    title = each['item']['product_description']['title']
    buy_url = each['item']['enrichment']['buy_url']
    image_url = each['item']['enrichment']['images']['primary_image_url']        
    print(title)
```

**Output:**

```
Ruffles Cheddar &#38; Sour Cream Potato Chips - 2.5oz
Doritos 3D Crunch Chili Cheese Nacho - 6oz
Hippeas Vegan White Cheddar Organic Chickpea Puffs - 5oz
PopCorners Spicy Queso - 7oz
Doritos 3D Crunch Spicy Ranch - 6oz
Pringles Snack Stacks Variety Pack Potato Crisps Chips - 12.9oz/18ct
Frito-Lay Variety Pack Flavor Mix - 18ct
Doritos Nacho Cheese Chips - 9.75oz
Hippeas Nacho Vibes Organic Chickpea Puffs - 5oz
Tostitos Scoops Tortilla Chips -10oz
Ripple Potato Chips Party Size - 13.5oz - Market Pantry&#8482;
Ritz Crisp & Thins Cream Cheese & Onion Potato And Wheat Chips - 7.1oz
Pringles Sour Cream &#38; Onion Potato Crisps Chips - 5.5oz
Original Potato Chips Party Size - 15.25oz - Market Pantry&#8482;
Organic White Corn Tortilla Chips - 12oz - Good & Gather&#8482;
Sensible Portions Sea Salt Garden Veggie Straws - 7oz
Traditional Kettle Chips - 8oz - Good & Gather&#8482;
Lay's Classic Potato Chips - 8oz
Cheetos Crunchy Flamin Hot - 8.5oz
Sweet Potato Kettle Chips - 7oz - Good & Gather&#8482;
SunChips Harvest Cheddar Flavored Wholegrain Snacks - 7oz
Frito-Lay Variety Pack Classic Mix - 18ct
Doritos Cool Ranch Chips - 10.5oz
Lay's Wavy Original Potato Chips - 7.75oz
Frito-Lay Variety Pack Family Fun Mix - 18ct
Cheetos Jumbo Puffs - 8.5oz
Frito-Lay Fun Times Mix Variety Pack - 28ct
Doritos Nacho Cheese Flavored Tortilla Chips - 15.5oz
Lay's Barbecue Flavored Potato Chips - 7.75oz
SunChips Garden Salsa Flavored Wholegrain Snacks - 7oz
Pringles Snack Stacks Variety Pack Potato Crisps Chips - 12.9oz/18ct
Frito-Lay Variety Pack Doritos & Cheetos Mix - 18ct
```

Comment: thank you for answer. my question, does walmart have own api ? thats why you use `https://redsky.target.com/redsky_aggregations/v1/web/plp_search_v1` ?

Comment: looks like they do: `https://www.walmart.com/search/api/wpa`

Comment: I mixed with "target" sorry :) I mean, target

Comment: ah yes. Target has an api. Yes, that's why I use that redsky address

Comment: one question, if I want to get chips in 2nd page, what should I change in payload ?

Comment: change `offset: '0'`. The offset will be `(page number - 1) * count`. So if you want page 2, it would be (2 - 1) * 28, which is `offset: '28'`. page 3 the `offset: '56'`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try instead

```
product_names = bot.find_elements_by_css_selector('Link-sc-1khjl8b-0.styles__StyledTitleLink-mkgs8k-5.kdCHb.inccCG.h-display-block.h-text-bold.h-text-bs.flex-grow-one')
```

When using `find_elements_by_class_name()`, spaces in the class name are not handled properly.

Except that selector doesn't work for me, I need to use `'.Link-sc-1khjl8b-0.ItemLink-sc-1eyz3ng-0.kdCHb.dtKueh'`

Comment: if I use with `'.Link-sc-1khjl8b-0.ItemLink-sc-1eyz3ng-0.kdCHb.dtKueh'``, it shows strange links. Also I need chips names